# quiz on HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()

Tags: java

Who can tell me whether the Java EE rules require the `HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval()` method to reset the lastAccessTime or to refresh the session instance?

For example:

The default session timeout time is 20 minutes. I logged in, and after 10 minutes I got this web application's session in another web application and called the method `setMaxInactiveInterval()` in the other web application. Both web applications run in the same domain and on the same machine. The web container is Weblogic 11g.

The result is:

After calling this method, there are 20 minutes remaining. I don't know whether the remaining time should be 10 minutes or 20 minutes? If it should be 10 minutes, by which Java EE spec rule is this governed?

Comment: I didn't get you properly. setMaxInactiveInterval() seems to set that value. U must have called method t oget max inactive interval . Isn't it? It will always return you the time  you had set.

Comment: If you have to calculate inactive time elapsed for any session, you will have to subtract  his last accessed time from current time.

Comment: in fact i dont know how to describe the theme. i just want to know if the lastAccessTime should be set to a new time after i invoke this method.